# Why does a String Array's "Count" Intellisensed property morph into "Length"?

Tags: c#, count, resharper, intellisense

I've got this code to see how many distinct fields/columns are being returned from a SQL Server Stored Proc (dtPriceComplianceResults is a DataTable that has been populated with the results of the SP):

```
string[] columnNames = dtPriceComplianceResults.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                .ToArray();
```

When I add this code directly below:

```
if (columnNames.
```

...Intellisense gives me a "*Count*" option; when I select the Enter key to accept it, though, it morphs it into "Length" - it won't let me choose "Count" even though that is in the list of available properties to access.

**Note:** By "morphed" I mean when I hit "Enter" the text that is appended to "columnNames." is "Length" not "Count", so that it ends up as "columnNames.Length"

It does compile that way (using "Length"), and with "Count" it does not ("*Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'*").

I guess this is a good thing, but if "Count" is not going to be really selectable, why does it show up in the list?

Comment: Define "morph". What happens visually? Do you have ReSharper installed and active? I've never seen it select an alternative by itself. Obviuously `Count` is an extension method, so it'd be `columnNames.Count() > `.

Comment: Yes; I was wondering if it was maybe Resharper...

Comment: I've never heard of such a beast, but you may be right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It's a ReSharper 10 "typo protection" option](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Completion_Tips_and_Tricks.html):

> **Correcting Length/Count mistyping**
>
> ReSharper prevents you from stumbling over mistyped Length/Count properties of arrays/collections. As soon as you erroneously start typing the Count property for a usage of an array, ReSharper will allow you to pick it from the completion list and replace with the Length property, which you probably meant to type.

You can see in the member info popup (the tooltip to the right of the IntelliSense dropdown) that it'll be replaced by `System.Array.Length`.

If you want the `Count()` extension method instead, you'll have to select the Count option prepended with the pink-with-arrow extension method icon, not the top one with the grey autocomplete icon:

[image]

Comment: So why does it allow you to see "Count" at all - shouldn't it preempt that? Or is it saying to itself (so to speak), "this cat will probably choose "Count" - we'll let him do that, but then give him something better"?

Answer (score 2):

`Count()` is a method, not a property. That's why you get the "cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' ..." error.

It is an extension method for `IEnumerable` and the implementation will (eventually) return `Array.Length`.

You could use it but it's less efficient than the simple (and direct) `Length`.

Intellisense or Resharper is doing the right thing.

Comment: OP's problem is: IntelliSense shows "Count", OP presses Enter, text editor shows "Length" instead. I don't think this is a "Count() vs Length" question. :)

Comment: To be fair, `Count` is also a property of the `ICollection` interface that arrays (explicitly) implement. But it wouldn't be accessible in that context.